# 'Instantiation of bean failed; Is it an abstract class?' When trying to instantiate a bean with an abstract parent

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to instantiate a bean, without a class definition, on Spring context by inheriting a parent bean, which is abstract. Like this:

```
<bean id="childBean" parent="abstractBean">
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="abstractBean" class="com.java.bean.AbstractBeanClass" 
        abstract="true" />
```

But Spring is giving me the following error message:

```
Error creating bean with name 'childBean' defined in class path resource 
    [project-spring.xml]: 
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Could not instantiate bean class [com.java.bean.AbstractBeanClass]: 
Is it an abstract class?;
nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException
...
```

<s>I remember having this in another project, and it works perfectly.</s>
I remember having this in the same project, and it works perfectly.

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE 1**
Found another bean being intatiated exactly like the way I mentioned:

```
<bean id="variantOptionDataConverter" parent="abstractPopulatingConverter">
    ...
</bean>
```

**UPDATE 2**
Declaration of the Abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractBeanClass<SOURCE, TARGET>
        extends AbstractConverter<SOURCE, TARGET>
        implements PopulatorList<SOURCE, TARGET>
{
...
}
```

Note: There's other classes that extends this class. None of the "other spring beans that works" I mentioned above extends this class.

Note 2: I know that it's weird, and, by Java fundamentals, it should not work (like everyone mentioned). But, I don't know how, the other Spring beans are being put in the context. I tried to copy the "other spring beans that work" into my code, change some duplicated names, and it worked. And, that's what I'm trying to understand...

Comment: _I remember having this in another project, and it works perfectly._ You must have something else going on, proxying of some kind maybe. This, as is, will never work.

Comment: Also, `abstract` bean declarations have nothing to do with `abstract` classes. They are simply bean templates, so that child beans inherit the `abstract` bean's properties.

Comment: Yep, I know that. But, I found another bean in the same project doing exactly like the way i mentioned, and it's working. (Updated the question with the actual names).
I didn't found any proxies or something out of the XML bean definition...

Comment: Unless you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we can only guess that something else is going on. **You cannot instantiate an `abstract` class.** It ends there. You'd think you are, but you aren't. If you want to know what is going on, you'll have to show us exactly what you are doing. Here's the link to how to create an MCVE again: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Juliano this should have a hybris tag as well as the problem is somewhat hybris specific (see my answer)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer:

Indeed, like [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) commented, *"You must have something else going on, proxying of some kind maybe"*, Spring has a proxy that instantiate this type of bean declaration, but it can't instantiate the bean without its methods (which are just declared in the abstract class, not implemented).
So you must "implement" these methods, like this:

```
<bean id="childBean" parent="abstractBean">
   <lookup-method name="notImplementedMethod" bean="anotherBean"/>
</bean>
```

The *anotherBean* must be the same type as *notImplementedMethod*.

Answer (score 2):

This concrete example Juliano is referring to is from the hybris commerce suite.
Hybris has the concept of extensions that have dependencies on each other. Each extension defines their own application context which has access to its inherited application contexts (from those extensions that are declared as dependencies).

In this example there is an abstractPopulatingConverter bean declaration declared at the root application context where its declared java class is abstract.
However, in other application context further down the dependency tree there is an alias definition for this "abstractPopulatingConverter" that points to a bean definitions with a concrete class.
That's why in a lot of cases (namely the ones that are even further down the dependency tree) using the parent="abstractPopulatingConverter" works as it points to the new bean defined by the alias.

Answer (score 1):

This is the very common message when Spring container faces with absatract Java class (not abstract bean). Check your com.java.bean.AbstractBeanClass code and probably you can find "public abstract class".

Comment: Yes, ''com.java.bean.AbstractBenClass'' is abstract (class and bean definition). The question is, why it works with another bean declaration, and not with mine? (both are in the same project)

Comment: It should not work as this contradicts to Java fundamentals. Can you compare working class declaration and non-working one (and publish all them here). I believe working class is not declared as abstract, but you have just abstract Spring bean there. Consider what abstract bean and abstract class are quite different things. Also, might be some proxing effect here. Please give us class declarations as they are.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing here?

I don't know what's going on in your other project, but Spring cannot instantiate beans for classes that are `abstract`.

Concerning `abstract` beans, the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions) states

> A child bean definition inherits configuration data from a parent definition.
>
> [...]
>
> A child bean definition uses the bean class from the parent definition
>   if none is specified, but can also override it. In the latter case,
>   the child bean class must be compatible with the parent, that is, it
>   must accept the parent’s property values.

In other words, an bean definition declared with `abstract="true"` is simply used as a template for other beans.

Java does not allow instantiation of `abstract` classes. Spring cannot overrule this language feature. Spring cannot instantiate beans of `abstract` class types.